# Ranking Variables and showing their names

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a ranking using variables in java.

I've created a GUI (using netbeans) with 8 buttons, each one adds 1 to a different variable.
My goal is to create a ranking with the most clicked buttons.

---

**For example:**

If button1 was clicked 10 times, the variable button1 gets the first place.

If button2 was clicked 8 times, the variable button2 gets the second place, and so on.

Then when I click on the button "Calculate" the name of the most clicked buttons appear in a text field.

---

**What I Already Done:**

I have declared 8 variables as classes atributes, each one is an int called buttonX (X being the number of the button).

Each button adds 1 to the its own variable. Like (`button1 = button1 + 1;`)

Now I just need to calculate the the biggest values and rank them, then put it's names on the text fields using this command:`jTextField3.setText(VARIABLE_NAME_HERE);`

I have no idea what to do, except to check if every value is bigger than the other one for each place.

---

**Extra Detail**

I want the first letter of each variable to be in capital letter.

Can you guys give some help/insight/ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need not have individual variables... You can achieve them using a Map like below

your actionPerformed() of all those 8 buttons can be like below

```
private void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    JButton b = (JButton) ae.getSource();
    int clickCount = map.get(b.getText());
    map.put(b.getText(), clickCount + 1);

    //Iterate the map and get the key with maximum value and show that in the jTextField3
}
```